# How to customise Windows Taskbar's Immersive Context Menu (Jump List) for Java application

Tags: java, windows, javafx, taskbar, jump-list

**How to customise Windows Taskbar's Immersive Context Menu (Jump List) for Java application?** (Add custom items to it)

I have JavaFX program (executable **exe** file), when I run it, it has an icon in taskbar (like other normal programs), its Immersive Context Menu has default options:

[image: default Immersive Context Menu]

Executing of **jar** file looks so:

[image]
*It looks like jar file can't have this feature. (Although I have created the ftype association and I can run jar files the same way as exe files by double clicking.) Or can?*

---

**I want to customise it – add my menu items like it do other programs.**

For example, Chrome and Atom (Electron application):

[image: Chrome Immersive Context Menu]
[image: Atom Immersive Context Menu]

*Upd: This feature called "Jump List".*

Comment: See if this helps. -> https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/e231e89e8d36ef4e5d8a

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of any way for java to change the jump menu. When you run a java file it's actually running java.exe with your jar as an argument. And even when you build an exe file its usually just a bundled launcher for your app. As far as I know in order to add a jump menu you would need something much closer to the metal.